# Translating “newsletter” or “bulletin”

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation

Is there any analogue of English *newsletter* or French *bulletin* in Latin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! Acta Diurna!

A quick note from Lewis and Short:

> B. acta publĭca , or absol.: acta , ōrum, n., the register of public acts, records, journal. Julius Cæsar, in his consulship, ordered that the doings of the Senate (diurna acta) should be made public, Suet. Caes. 20; cf. Ernest. Exc. 1; “but Augustus again prohibited it,” Suet. Aug. 36. Still the acts of the Senate were written down, and, under the succeeding emperors. certain senators were appointed to this office (actis vel commentariis Senatūs conficiendis), Tac. A. 5, 4. They had also public registers of the transactions of the assemblies of the people, and of the different courts of justice; “also of births and deaths, marriages, divorces, etc., which were preserved as sources of future history.—Hence, diurna urbis acta,” the city journal, Tac. A. 13, 31: “acta populi,” Suet. Caes. 20: “acta publica,” Tac. A. 12, 24; Suet. Tib. 8; Plin. Ep. 7, 33: “urbana,” id. ib. 9, 15; which were all comprehended under the gen. name acta.

From [Smith's Dictionary](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/secondary/SMIGRA*/Acta.html#5):

> Acta Diurna, a gazette published daily at Rome by the authority of the government during the later times of the republic, and under the empire, corresponding in some measure to our newspapers (Tac. Ann. III.3, XIII.31, XVI.22). In addition to the title Acta Diurna, we find them referred to under the names of Diurna, Acta Publica,  p8 Acta Urbana, Acta Rerum Urbanarum, Acta Populi, and they are frequently called simply Acta. The Greek writers on Roman history call them τὰ ὐπομνήματα, τὰ δημόσια ὐπομνήματα, τὰ δημόσια γράμματα, and τὰ κοινὰ ὐπομνήματα. The nature of their contents will be best seen from the following passage of Petronius (c53) where in imitation of them is given by the actuarius of Trimalchio:— "Actuarius — tamquam acta urbis recitavit: VII. Kal. Sextilis in praedio Cumano, quod est Trimalchionis, nati sunt pueri XXX, puellae XL; sublata in horreum ex area tritici millia modium quingenta; boves domiti quingenti. Eodem die Mithridates servus in crucem actus est, quia Gaii nostri genio maledixerat. Eodem die in aream relatum est, quod collocari non potuit, sestertium centies. Eodem die incendium factum est in hortis Pompeianis, ortum ex aedibus Nastae villici. Jam etiam edicta aedilium recitabantur, et saltuariorum testamenta, quibus Trimalchio cum elogio exhaeredabatur; jam nomina villicorum et repudiata a circumitore liberta in balneatoris contubernio deprehensa; atriensis Baias relegatus; jam reus factus dispensator; et judicium inter cubicularios actum." From this passage, and from the numerous passages in ancient writers, in which the Acta Diurna are quoted (references to which are given in the works of Le Clerc and Lieberkühnº cited below), it would appear that they usually contained the following matters:— 1. The number of births and deaths in the city, an account of the money paid into the treasury from the provinces, and every thing relating to the supply of corn.º These particulars would be extracted from the tabulae publicae. By an ancient regulation, ascribed to Servius Tullius (Dionys. IV.15), all births were registered in the temple of Venus, and all deaths in that of Libitina; and we know that this practice was continued under the empire, only that at a later time the temple of Saturn was substituted for that of Venus for the registration of births (Jul. Cap. M. Aurel. 9). 2. Extracts from the Acta Forensia, containing the edicts of magistrates, the testaments of distinguished men, reports of trials, with the names of those who were acquitted and condemned, and likewise a list of the magistrates who were elected. 3. Extracts from the acta senatus, especially all the decrees and acclamationes [Acclamatio] in honour of the reigning emperor. 4. A court circular, containing an account of the birth, deaths, festivals, and movements of the imperial family. 5. An account of such public affairs and foreign wars as the government thought proper to publish. 6. Curious and interesting occurrences, such as prodigies and miracles, the erection of new edifices, the conflagration of buildings, funerals, sacrifices, a list of the various games, and especially amatory tales and adventures, with the names of the parties (comp. Cic. ad Fam. II.15).

Comment: This is also the expression we chose for [our meta announcement](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/423/79).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Well, isn't that a coincidence!

Answer (score 4):

Before Gutenberg's printing press, the concept of a "newsletter" didn't really exist—producing dozens of written copies of weekly announcements just wasn't cost-effective for your average citizen. So the best option will probably be an analogy.

*Nūntius* can mean either an envoy, a courier, or a message delivered by a courier. In the plural, *nūntiī*, it can also mean "news" or "tidings"; it is in fact cognate with English "news". So you could refer to your newsletter as *nūntiī*: "the news" or "the announcements".

Alternately, *bulla* literally means "bubble", but later came to mean a seal on a document. Important announcements and other documents were sealed with a *bulla*, and thus came to be known as *bullae* themselves—this is how we get "papal bulls" in English. So you could potentially call a single newsletter a *bulla* by analogy.

Finally, *litterae* (almost always plural, even when referring to a single object) means "letter", plain and simple. If you want to emphasize a piece of paper being sent through the mail, as opposed to a set of announcements sent out en masse, *litterae* could work for that.

Between the three, I'd recommend *nūntiī*; it's more closely connected to a Classical word, while *bulla* meaning a document is Mediaeval, so I expect *nūntiī* to be more widely understood nowadays; and *litterae* don't necessarily have any connection to news or announcements, which are the main point of a bulletin.